# Any subring of $A$ is an ideal. If $A$ is an integral domain then $A$ is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

Any subring of $A$  is an ideal. If $A$ is an integral domain then $A$ is commutative.

Is my proof correct?

So let $a$ and $b$ nonzero elements of $A$.

$C(a)=\{ x\in A \mid ax=xa\}$

Is a subring and an ideal of $A$, so $ba\in C(a)$.

Then $a (ba)=(ba)a$

$aba-baa=0$

$(ab-ba)a=0$

And $A$ is an integral domain, $a$ is nonzero:

$ab-ba=0$

$ab=ba$

Comment: Commutativity is apart of the definition of an Integral Domain.  A domain is one where multiplication is not necessarily commutative.

Comment: Yes, it looks fine.

Comment: Looks like it should be pointed out the context of the proof is apparently rings possibly without identity. If you don't explicitly mention that you aren't assuming identity, someone is going to say this: $Cent(A)$ is an ideal and contains $1$. If $Cent(A)$ is an ideal, it is all of $A$. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely correct. Padding goes here.